# Using nested function with dot operator in js

Tags: javascript, function, object

Hey guys am new to javascript app development..My code

```
var obj = {
    models: "AN",
    collection: {},
    person: {},

    changeDetails: function(values, babes) {
        obj.person.name = values.name;
        obj.person.age = values.age;
    }

    babe: function() {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

When i called it like `obj.changeDetails({name:"George",age:20}).babe());` it throws me error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Is it possible in javascript to call like `objectname.functionname.().anotherfunctionname()`??.If its possible please post it as an answer showing its demonstration..

Thanks

Comment: @thefourtheye, not sure it was a good idea to add in that missing comma in your edit. That might have been part of the problem...

Comment: You can read about function chaining (i.e. in jQuery) to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`changeDetails` doesn't return anything.  You can't call `.babe()` on nothing.

```
var obj = {
    models: "AN",
    collection: {},
    person: {},

    changeDetails: function(values, babes) {
        obj.person.name = values.name;
        obj.person.age = values.age;

        return obj;
    },

    babe: function() {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

Now you can chain stuff, since `changeDetails` returns an object:

```
obj.changeDetails({name:"George",age:20}).babe();
```

Answer (score 4):

**You got 2 syntax errors and 1 logic error**

You're missing a comma (`,`) after

```
changeDetails: function (values, babes) {
    obj.person.name = values.name;
    obj.person.age = values.age;
}
```

So it should be

```
var obj = {
   models: "AN",
    collection: {},
    person: {},
    changeDetails: function(values, babes) {
        obj.person.name = values.name;
        obj.person.age = values.age;
    },
    babe: function() {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

Also, you got one too-many right parenthesis (`)`) after

```
obj.changeDetails({name:"George",age:20}).babe());
```

It should be

```
obj.changeDetails({name:"George",age:20}).babe();
```

Finally, to be able to call the method `babe` of the object you must return it within the `changeDetails` function, it makes sense to use `this` in this context.

**Final Solution**

```
var obj = {
    models: "AN",
    collection: {},
    person: {},

    changeDetails: function(values, babes) {
        this.person.name = values.name;
        this.person.age = values.age;
        return this;
    },
    babe: function() {
        return 5;
    }
};
obj.changeDetails({name:"George",age:20}).babe();
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply want to return `this`:

```
changeDetails: function(values, babes) {
    obj.person.name = values.name;
    obj.person.age = values.age;
    return this;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `chaining`, you must return the `obj` in every it method:

```
var obj = {
    models: "AN",
    collection: {},
    person: {},
    changeDetails: function (values, babes) {
        obj.person.name = values.name;
        obj.person.age = values.age;
        return obj;
    },
    babe: function () {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

Comment: how can i call this function ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very well possible. You just need to design your functions in such a way that, they allow chaining of functions possible. For example,

```
changeDetails: function(values, babes) {
    obj.person.name = values.name;
    obj.person.age = values.age;
    return obj;                            # Return the `obj`
},
```

Now, the result of the function call `changeDetails` is `obj`, which has `babe` function now. So, you can invoke it like this

```
obj.changeDetails({
    name: "George",
    age: 20
}).babe();
```

Also note that, you don't use the second parameter `babes` in the `changeDetails` function. So, you can drop that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say if you're assigning babe status you should at least be returning an 8 - 10 like so - Also you need to return obj in your change details.

```
var obj = {
    models: "AN",
    collection: {},
    person: {},

    changeDetails: function(values, babes) {
        obj.person.name = values.name;
        obj.person.age = values.age;
        return obj;
    }

    babe: function() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random()*(10-8+1)+8))
    }
};
```

Comment: You're missing a comma.